# Oracle PLSQL Array will not allow me to Index or Extend

Tags: oracle, multidimensional-array, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracle-type

```
create or replace TYPE csv_rec IS OBJECT (client_code varchar2(500),
                                          debtor_code varchar2(500));
```

--

```
create or replace TYPE csv_table IS TABLE OF csv_rec;
--
PROCEDURE Create_Detail
(xClientCode IN NUMBER 
,xStatus IN OUT VARCHAR2
,xWebCursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
--
    l_client_code        NUMBER;
    l_array              csv_table;
--
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT t1.field1,
           t2.field2
    FROM table1 t1,
         table2 t2
    WHERE t1.client_code = l_client_code
    AND t1.client_code = t2.client_code;
--
    c_rec c1%ROWTYPE;
--
BEGIN
    --
    l_client_code := xClientCode;
    --
    l_array := csv_table();
    --
    FOR c_rec IN c1
    --
    LOOP
        --
        l_array.extend;
        l_array := csv_table(csv_rec(c_rec.field1,c_rec.field2));
        --
    END LOOP;   
    --
    OPEN xWebCursor FOR 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_array);
    --
    xStatus := 'TRUE';
    --
EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         xStatus := 'FALSE';
END Create_Detail;
```

I am having trouble that the above code will always populate the array with the final row in the cursor. I don't know how to get the 'extend' to work, or move to 'next' row in the array. It will not allow me to use l_array(index) at all so I am stumped? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using bulk collect into instead of loop,

**Note:- In case you are dealing with huge data set try suing limit with bulk collect into.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_detail_constructor
(xclientcode IN NUMBER,xstatus     IN OUT VARCHAR2,xwebcursor  IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
   l_client_code NUMBER;
   l_array       csv_table := csv_table();
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT csv_rec(t1.field1,t2.field2)
      FROM   (SELECT 1 client_code
                    ,'1 F1' field1
              FROM   dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 client_code
                    ,'2 F2' field1
              FROM   dual) t1
            ,(SELECT 1 client_code
                    ,'1 F1 T2' field2
              FROM   dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 1 client_code
                    ,'1 F2 T2' field2
              FROM   dual) t2
      WHERE  t1.client_code = l_client_code
      AND    t1.client_code = t2.client_code;
BEGIN
   --
   l_client_code := xclientcode;
   --
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
     FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO l_array ;
     EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
   --
   OPEN xwebcursor FOR
      SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_array);
   --
   xstatus := 'TRUE';
   --
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      xstatus := 'FALSE';
END create_detail_constructor;
```

--Test

```
DECLARE
   xwebcursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
   xstatus     VARCHAR2(100) := 'A';
   xclientcode NUMBER := 1;
   l_field1    VARCHAR2(100);
   l_field2    VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   -- Call the procedure
   create_detail_constructor(xclientcode => xclientcode
                ,xstatus     => xstatus
                ,xwebcursor  => xwebcursor);
   LOOP
      FETCH xwebcursor
         INTO l_field1
             ,l_field2;
      EXIT WHEN xwebcursor%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_field1 || '-' || l_field2);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE xwebcursor;
END;
```

If we want to do the same with loop then we need to declare another type and use multiset union to append the result (at least I know this way)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_detail
(xclientcode IN NUMBER,xstatus     IN OUT VARCHAR2,xwebcursor  IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
   l_client_code NUMBER;
   l_array       csv_table;
   l_array_final csv_table := csv_table();
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT t1.field1
            ,t2.field2
      FROM   (SELECT 1 client_code
                    ,'1 F1' field1
              FROM   dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 client_code
                    ,'2 F2' field1
              FROM   dual) t1
            ,(SELECT 1 client_code
                    ,'1 F1 T2' field2
              FROM   dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 1 client_code
                    ,'1 F2 T2' field2
              FROM   dual) t2
      WHERE  t1.client_code = l_client_code
      AND    t1.client_code = t2.client_code;
   c_rec c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   --
   l_client_code := xclientcode;
   --
   l_array := csv_table();
   --
   FOR c_rec IN c1
   --
   LOOP
      --
      l_array.extend;
      l_array := csv_table(csv_rec(c_rec.field1
                                  ,c_rec.field2));
      l_array_final := l_array_final MULTISET UNION l_array;
   END LOOP;
   --
   OPEN xwebcursor FOR
      SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_array_final);
   --
   xstatus := 'TRUE';
   --
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      xstatus := 'FALSE';
END create_detail;
```

--Test

```
DECLARE
   xwebcursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
   xstatus     VARCHAR2(100) := 'A';
   xclientcode NUMBER := 1;
   l_field1    VARCHAR2(100);
   l_field2    VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   -- Call the procedure
   create_detail(xclientcode => xclientcode
                ,xstatus     => xstatus
                ,xwebcursor  => xwebcursor);
   LOOP
      FETCH xwebcursor
         INTO l_field1
             ,l_field2;
      EXIT WHEN xwebcursor%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_field1 || '-' || l_field2);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE xwebcursor;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I had simplified the code as the issue was evident even as is. Will definitely look to incorporate some of your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Nice you found a way out , i didn't think that way. If we go for production code i would suggest to go with bulk collect to deal with object types

Comment: @Chris, if you go for bulk collect, which is better and faster, just be aware that it requires more memory. You can always apply the LIMIT clause to the BULK COLLECT to iterate by groups of rows.

Comment: Thanks so much for the additional info @Roberto. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
PROCEDURE Create_Detail
(xClientCode IN NUMBER 
,xStatus IN OUT VARCHAR2
,xWebCursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
--
    l_client_code        NUMBER;
    l_loop_var           NUMBER := 1;
    l_array_rec          csv_rec := csv_rec(null,null);
    l_array              csv_table : csv_table();
--
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT t1.field1,
           t2.field2
    FROM table1 t1,
         table2 t2
    WHERE t1.client_code = l_client_code
    AND t1.client_code = t2.client_code;
--
    c_rec c1%ROWTYPE;
--
BEGIN
    --
    l_client_code := xClientCode;
    --
    FOR c_rec IN c1
    --
    LOOP
        --
        l_array_rec.client_code := c1.field1;
        l_array_rec.debtor_code := c2.field2;
        --
        l_array.extend;
        l_array(l_loop_var) := l_array_rec;
        --
        l_loop_var := l_loop_var + 1;
        --
    END LOOP;   
    --
    OPEN xWebCursor FOR 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_array);
    --
    xStatus := 'TRUE';
    --
EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         xStatus := 'FALSE';
END Create_Detail;
```

Found the fix was to include the additional declaration of the Object Type and then could add the index. The Extend then worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you construct the `csv_rec` object directly in the cursor, you can save a lot of processing steps.

```
create or replace procedure create_detail
    ( xClientCode in number
    , xStatus     in out varchar2
    , xWebCursor  in out sys_refcursor )
as
    l_client_code number := xClientCode;
    l_array       csv_table := csv_table();
begin
    for r in (
        select csv_rec(t1.field1, t2.field2) as csv
        from   table1 t1
               join table2 t2 on t2.client_code = t1.client_code
        where  t1.client_code = l_client_code;
    )
    loop
        l_array.extend;
        l_array(l_array.count) := r.csv;
    end loop;

    open xWebCursor for
        select * from table(l_array);

    xStatus := 'TRUE';

exception
    when others then
        xStatus := 'FALSE';
end create_detail;
```

But you can do it without a loop:

```
create or replace procedure create_detail
    ( xClientCode in number
    , xStatus     in out varchar2
    , xWebCursor  in out sys_refcursor )
as
    l_client_code number := xClientCode;
    l_array       csv_table := csv_table();
begin
    select csv_rec(t1.field1, t2.field2) bulk collect into l_array
    from   table1 t1
           join table2 t2 on t2.client_code = t1.client_code
    where  t1.client_code = l_client_code;

    open xWebCursor for
        select * from table(l_array);

    xStatus := 'TRUE';

exception
    when others then
        xStatus := 'FALSE';
end create_detail;
```

You could do it without the object type and the array as well, by just returning the cursor, but presumably this is a simplified version and the real code needs the array for something.

The `others` exception handler is risky. Maybe it should be `when no_data_found`, and let anything else be a real exception and fail. What if it's something unexpected like `ORA-01578: ORACLE data block corrupted`?

(Edit: just noticed Sujitmohanty30 was first to suggest the inline object constructor.)

Just as a comment, *objects* and *records* are two different things, and normally *CSV* stands for Comma-Separated Values, so `csv_rec` is a slightly confusing name for an object type.

Also I've always found neat code makes it easier to take in the structure and spot errors or overcomplicated steps, so I removed all the empty comments, and also the uppercase because it isn't 1974 any more. I think the result is a lot easier to read.